# Запрос на выборку количества типов по годам

Tags: sql-server

Есть 2 таблицы, можно ли одним запросом выбрать записи, сгруппированные по типам (именам) и годам с указанием количества? А если одним запросом нельзя - то как оптимальным образом это можно сделать?

```
[NAME]
ID|NAME
-------
1  Вася
2  Маша
3  Петя

[DATA]
ID|ID_N|SDATE
-------------
1  1    2008
2  1    2008
3  1    2010
4  2    2011
<...>
```

Результат:

```
        2008  2010  2011
Вася    2     1     0
Маша    0     0     1
Петя    0     0     0
```

Comment: количество дат не ограничено?

Comment: группируете по датам и именам, а на количество делаете подзапрос.

Comment: @Saidolim Да, не ограничено.

Comment: Тут даже подзапрос делать не надо, просто COUNT(id) в select'е, а остальные поля группировать.

Comment: Это на PIVOT таблицу тянет... Просто убедиться - это MSSQL? потому что в MySQL этого нет... Из-за неограниченного кол-ва дат в один запрос этого не сделать. надо будет процедуру делать...

Comment: @Ella Svetlaya Вот бы такой запрос увидеть бы)

Comment: @cyadvert Да, MSSQL. PIVOT, судя по описанию, в чистом виде не подойдет. А процедура какого вида, что она должна делать в данном случае?

Comment: В процедуре два запроса. Первый берет distinct даты, которые будут использоваться как наименования столбцов во втором запросе - PIVOTe

Comment: @cyadvert Ваш комментарий направил меня к нужному (скорее всего) решению! [Вот еще немного об этом](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте таким образом

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = ISNULL(@cols + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(SDATE)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SDATE FROM DATA) AS b;

set @query ='select *
from
(
select NAME, SDATE, count(*) cou
from NAME, DATA
where NAME.id = DATA.id_n
group by NAME, SDATE
  ) s
pivot (sum(cou) for SDATE in ('+@cols+')) pvt'

  execute(@query)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, практически так же сделал. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - как сортировка дат в подзапросе. Пришлось применить _SELECT TOP 99.999 PERCENT_

Comment: а изменить @cols на `SELECT DISTINCT SDATE FROM DATA ORDER BY SDATE` не помогло?

Comment: [Вот здесь про это написано](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985921/sql-error-with-order-by-in-subquery)